# scale and draw image inside a lager canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction to how i might go about solving this issue.

I have a blank image (white) which is 3000x1500 which acts a a canvas, i then have an image which again could be any size and any orientation.  What i need to do is scale this image to fit inside the blank white canvas as best as possible and also center it.  I would expect to see white gaps at the top or bottom of the final image if the image could not be scaled to fix the exact canvas.

Can anyone suggest what i should research, how i would go about drawing an image inside another in C# WPF and anything that may already exist that i could use to achieve this.

I forgot to mention that this would need to output to a bitmap so it could be saved to disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to put an Image control into an appropriately sized Grid with white background, and set its `Stretch` property to `Uniform`. No Viewbox required.

```
<Grid Width="3000" Height="1500" Background="White">
    <Image Source="<path to image file>" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i would need this to be exported to a jpeg so this would need to be done in the code behind. Have updated my question

Comment: You can draw the Grid to a RenderTargetBitmap.

Answer (score -1):

Look up ViewBox. A ViewBox automatically scales its single child element based off of the stretch parameter.